# how to install pip remotely using ssh

Tags: django, python-2.7, pip

Hi I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

I am trying to upload a django project which I have developed locally on my machine and now moved the project files to a server and am trying to install django on the server.

I have Python 2.7.5 installed and accessed the server remotely using ssh (putty) I can confirm Python is installed by running the command python --version

I don't have pip installed as when i run the command pip --version

I get following notification
-bash: pip: command not found

I am new to django and python so not sure what I should do to install both django and pip.

p.s In my requirements file and when working locally I have pip and django installed correctly and all working.

Comment: hi @Vinnie S - did you try the methods on the python documentation at this [link](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py)?  It says try curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py and then python get-pip.py

Comment: what is python version of your Django project?

Comment: @bSr Python version is 2.7.5

Comment: Hi Paul, Thank you for getting back I did try the documentation link you provided I ran the command python curl bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py then python get-pip.py i get an exception response trying to install pip, wheel?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, lets say you are already on your remote server. First thing to do is to install `pip` for your version of python. You can do this via:

`sudo apt-get install python-pip`

From now you have pip installed. Next thing to do is to install django globally in your system:

`pip install django==1.11`

> Please note that django 1.11 is the last version that supports
>   python2

Next thing to do is to create django app:

```
django-admin startproject test_project
```

And the last thing is to install `virtualenv`

> To install libraries for each of your django projects and keep them
>   separate

```
pip install virtualenv
```

> Also note

If you have requirements.txt file with all libs, you can do something like this on your remote server:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

That will automatically install all libraries at once

Comment: Hi @Madi7 I dont think i've made myself clear I have a project already created which is on my machine and i want to move the project to my server. I already have all the apps installed locally. I have python already installed on the server and need to run pip and django to get my application to work?

Comment: Are you storing your app on github or something ? If so just clone the repo direct into your server and everything will work just fine, let me know if you have some more questions

Answer (score 1):

First you should understand which OS you're running:

```
uname -a
```

and:

```
lsb_release -a
```

When you find the OS version, you can easily follow this guide:
https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-linux-tools/#installing-pip-setuptools-wheel-with-linux-package-managers

Comment: Hi @RColombo I ran the commands uname -a tells me its a Linux based OS the second command returns command not found?

Comment: @VinnieS try this: cat /etc/issue